# R networkD3: click action to show information from node data frame

Tags: javascript, r, networking, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have this code:

```
library(networkD3)

# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

new.nodes <- MisNodes
new.nodes$var1 <- runif(nrow(MisNodes),1,2)
new.nodes$var2 <- runif(nrow(MisNodes),1,2)

# Some script to show the node index in the new.nodes data frame
script <- 'alert("row: " + (d.index + 1));'

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = new.nodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8,
             clickAction = script)
```

I figured out to get the row number of the node data frame by asking for `d.index + 1`. However I want to show a table containing all the node info, like so (perhaps nicer formatted):

```
    name group size     var1     var2
1 Myriel     1   15 1.501311 1.053062
```

This would require the JavaScript to have access to the node data frame, as I only have little knowledge of JavaScript I cannot figure out how to request this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `forceNetwork` function strips out all the unnecessary variables/columns in the data frame that it passes to JavaScript, which is advantageous usually, but not in this case. You can work around it by saving the htmlwidget object that `forceNetwork` creates, then add back in the variable you need to access, and then 'print'/display it.

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

MisNodes$var1 <- runif(nrow(MisNodes),1,2)

script <- 'alert("var1: " + (d.var1));'

fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = new.nodes, Source = "source", 
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                   Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, clickAction = script)

fn$x$nodes$var1 <- MisNodes$var1

fn
```

[image]

---

This could be done with/for multiple variables as well, for example...

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

MisNodes$var1 <- runif(nrow(MisNodes),1,2)
MisNodes$var2 <- runif(nrow(MisNodes),1,2)

script <- 'alert("var1: " + d.var1 + "\\n" + "var2: " + d.var2);'

fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = new.nodes, Source = "source", 
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                   Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, clickAction = script)

fn$x$nodes$var1 <- MisNodes$var1
fn$x$nodes$var2 <- MisNodes$var2

fn
```

Comment: Aaah nice solution!

Comment: Nice. Do you know if this documented anywhere?

Comment: Documented? It's definitely not a secret that `forceNetwork` returns an htmlwidget, nor that an htmlwidget is editable, but specifically this hack is not documented anywhere that I am aware (other than here, now)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think it is not easily done if not impossible. It appears that only the used the arguments of `forceNetwork` relating to the nodes are initialized in the underlying code:

Consider for example:

```
script <- 'alert("row: "     + (d.index + 1) + 
                 ", name: "  + d.name + 
                 ", group: " + d.group + 
                 ", size: "  + d.nodesize + 
                 ", var1: "  + d.var1)'

# Plot
d3 <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = new.nodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
             Nodesize = "size",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8,
             clickAction = script)

print(d3)
```

As you can see when clicking a node below, the var1 is undefined. Note I added the `Nodesize` argument to the function call which now can be accessed through the script `d.nodesize` (and not `d.size`). The `group` variable and argument, in this case, are named identically so the distinction is lost here. However, the `NodeID` is apparently accessed by the stated name which I find inconsistent.

[image]

You can see the generated source by saving:

```
saveNetwork(d3, file = "test.html")
```

You can notice by looking at it, that the values you intend to output are not stored in the file.

## Edit:

By your own suggestion, this comes somewhat close as a workaround:

```
new.nodes$newname  <- with(new.nodes, paste(", name: ", name, ", group: ", group, 
                                ", size: ", size, ", var1: ", var1,
                                ", var2: ", var2))

newscript <- 'alert("row: " + (d.index + 1) + d.name)'

forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = new.nodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "newname", Nodesize = "size",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, opacityNoHover = 0,
             clickAction = newscript)
```

[image]

So, it is just a matter of formatting the string as you'd like it displayed. The downside is that name/NodeIDs are very long. And as you can see, the NodeID is just always called `name` on the JS side.

Comment: Perhaps I could merge all variables into one string (and separate this by a delimiter) then use this as NodeID, and use JS to split the data from d.name? (Don't know how to do this in JS though). Setting opacityNoHover = 0 would be smart then otherwise the whole text will appear

Comment: I guess that could work, yes. But why not just make the desired string on the R side?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it does work. Please see the edited post. I guess it is an acceptable "hack".

Comment: Nice! That will do it

Comment: @CodeNoob Glad I could help. *If* it answered your question, please consider accepting it.